# Why "has" but "doesn't have"

Tags: usage

Why is "has" correct in Sentence 1 and "have" correct in Sentence 2?

> 1. Earth **has** soil.
> 2. Mars doesn't **have** soil.

Comment: The obligatory tense and agreement are on *DO* (*does*) in 2, and *DO* takes an infinitive (*have*) complement.

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

StonyB has it right in a previous comment. To show in another way, say Earth has soil, but Mars has no soil. Or, say Earth does have soil, but Mars does not have soil. To make it scientifically correct as well as grammatically so, replace "soil" with "water".